# #define DEBUG 1

Tags: c, debugging

I'm trying to have a debugging mode on so if

```
#define DEBUG 1
```

I want to printf some variable values and if

```
#define DEBUG 0
```

I want them off.

The problem is I have many implementation files and I want this DEBUG variable to be available for the whole project. Right now I need to edit the DEBUG variable in foo1.c, foo2.c, foo3.c which seems tedious and error-prone and there must be a better way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

When compiling, you should be able to specify an option to your compiler. For example, you can call GCC with the `-DDEBUG` option.

In this case, you would be better using:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#endif
```

or:

```
#if defined(DEBUG)
#endif
```

if this is not the way you're doing it now. I'm surprised that you don't have a global header file for your project. Something along the lines of:

```
#undef DEBUG
#define DEBUG 1
```

in a file called "debug.h". In your C programs, you can include this by using `#include "debug.h"`

Comment: Is it not `gcc -DDEBUG` instead of `-dDEBUG`?

Comment: nop... -D is the right option (-U for undef) -d with a letter is to make debugging dumps during compilation at times specified by a letter

Comment: @Alan I misunderstood what you said... my bad :-)

Comment: @person-b and @LB: I should have rephrased my comment. It looks ambiguous. :-)

Comment: There is never a need for the sequence: #ifdef X / #undef X / #endif; you simply write: #undef X.  The compilers that did not like that when X was not defined died years ago; the C89 standard mandates that undefining an undefined macro is not an error.

Answer (score 17):

Try something like Steve McConnel suggests in section 6 of "Chapter 8:  Defensive Programming" from [Code Complete 2](http://cc2e.com/)...  Add this to your code:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#if (DEBUG > 0) && (DEBUG < 2)
printf("Debugging level 1");
#endif

#if (DEBUG > 1) && (DEBUG < 3)
printf("Debugging level 2");
#endif

#if (DEBUG > n-1) && (DEBUG < n)
printf("Debugging level n");
#endif
#endif
```

Then when you compile, add this flag (warning:  This might be compiler-dependent):

```
-DDEBUG=m
```

Or, have a global header that defines these sorts of things, as others have suggested.

Comment: nice sugestion but what is the name of the book?

Answer (score 6):

As a response to your problem you can also simply invoke the compiler like:

```
cc -c -DDEBUG=1
```

or

```
 cc -c -DDEBUG=0
```

You must delete the "define DEBUG 1/0" in your files - or replace it with:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#define DEBUG 0
#endif
```

Here is what I am using (GCC syntax):

- create a file debug.h with the following content and include it in each c file:

  ```
  #ifdef DEBUG
  extern FILE *dbgf;
  #define D_MIN   0x00010000  // Minimum level
  #define D_MED   0x00020000  // Medium level
  #define D_MAX   0x00040000  // Maximum level 
  #define D_FLUSH 0x00080000  // Usefull by a program crash
  #define D_TRACE 0x00100000  
  #define D_1     0x00000001  
  ...

  #define D(msk, fmt, args...) if(msk & dbgmsk) { fprintf(dbgf, "%s:",__FUNCTION__); fprintf(dbgf, fmt, ## args ); if(msk & D_FLUSH) fflush(dbgf); }
  #define P(msk, fmt, args...) if(msk & dbgmsk) { fprintf(dbgf, fmt, ## args ); if(msk & D_FLUSH) fflush(dbgf); }

  #else
  #define D(msk, fmt, args...)
  #define P(msk, fmt, args...)
  #endif
  ```

dbgmsk is variable, which can be global (whole program) or local/static and must be initialized a start. You can define several options for the whole program or for each module. This is better and more flexible than the version with the level variable.

Ex.
module1.c:

```
#include "debug.h"

static int dbgmsk;  // using local dbgmsk
module1_setdbg(int msk) { dbgmsk = msk; D(D_TRACE,"dbgmsk1=%x\n", dbgmsk); }

foo1() {  P(D_1, "foo1 function\n" ); 
  ....
}
foo2() {}
...
```

foo3.c

```
#include "debug.h"
extern int dbgmsk; // using global dbgmsk
```

Ex. main:

```
#include "debug.h"
FILE *dbgf;
int dbgmsk = 0; // this is the global dbgmsk

int main() { 
  dbgf = stderr; // or your logfile
  dbgmsk = D_MIN;
  module1_setdbg(D_MIN|D_MED|D_TRACE|D_1);
  ....
}
```

I'm also storing all dbgmsk variables in a config text file that is read at the program start.

Comment: It is better to ensure that the compiler always sees, but does not always act upon, the diagnostic printing.  The #else clause should do something like: #define D(msk, fmt, ...) do { if (0 && (msk & dbgmsk)) printf(fmt, __VARARGS__); } while (0).  The do/while idiom ensures that you can use this anywhere a statement can appear; the if (0) means that the code is never executed, and the compiler will optimize it away - but only after checking it for syntactic validity.  If you define the non-debug version to nothing, you do not get continuous checking that the debug code is syntactically valid.

Answer (score 5):

As @person-b says, specify this define as a compiler option, e.g. -D DEBUG

Note though that to simplify this you should change the test in your code from:

```
#if DEBUG
```

to:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
```

This way you don't have to worry about specifying a 0 or 1 value but can instead rely on it being defined or not.

Answer (score 4):

Put the "#define DEBUG" in "debug.h" and #include that header file in each *.c file.

Comment: May be not the right way to go.
Use the Makefile to manage the build mode, DEBUG or RELEASE.
So according to the build mode, vary what goes into the CFLAGS.
That approach will scale seamlessly.

Answer (score 2):

The suggestion from samoz and Stephen Doyle to check for the existence of a definition for DEBUG rather than its value is a good one. However, if you really want to use DEBUG=0, this is how you can do it: Each time you define the DEBUG flag (i.e., in each file), check for an existing definition:

```
#ifndef DEBUG
#define DEBUG 1
#endif
```

Then, when you use the option -DDEBUG=0 with your compiler, the #define line will never be executed.

Comment: I would reverse the default - DEBUG 0 normally, but overridable on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead.

In the first file you have that will be included:

```
#define DEBUG
```

Then whenever you want to have debug code, do this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
do some stuff
#endif
```

This will also prevent your debugging code from making it into release code.

Comment: I don't think you understood his question.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define IFDEBUG if(0)else
#else
#define IFDEBUG if(1)else
#endif
```