# # sign as a prefix in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone explain for me what the purpose when we are doing like this

```
 #if

 // block of codes goes here

 #endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are `preprocessor directives`. Preprocessor directives are lines included in the code of our programs that are not program statements but directives for the preprocessor. These lines are always preceded by a hash sign `(#)`. The preprocessor is executed before the actual compilation of code begins, therefore the preprocessor digests all these directives before any code is generated by the statements.

These preprocessor directives extend only across a single line of code. As soon as a newline character is found, the preprocessor directive is considered to end. No semicolon (;) is expected at the end of a preprocessor directive. The only way a preprocessor directive can extend through more than one line is by preceding the newline character at the end of the line by a backslash ().
For more detail refer [Preprocessor directives](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/preprocessor/) and [Using Objective-C Preprocessor Directives](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Objective-C_Preprocessor_Directives)

Answer (score 2):

They're C preprocessor directives. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the tags prefixed with # are directives to the preprocessor that result in a modification of the code that goes on to be compiled. More specifically, the example you present relates to conditional compilation. A common use case would relate to compiling in DEBUG versus RELEASE mode, where selected code would be included or excluded by the preprocessor as follows:

```
#define DEBUG
#ifdef DEBUG

// block of codes goes here - only survives preprocessing if in DEBUG mode

#endif
```

In this case the code may log an output message or perform some other action that you would only want to occur in DEBUG mode. If you wish to compile in DEBUG mode, you define DEBUG; otherwise, you simple comment it out. Alternatively, the definition of DEBUG can be performed with a compiler switch. Further discussion of that, and use of the preprocessor for debug mode conditional compilation in general, see question [987637/define-debug-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987637/define-debug-1).